# Bound function to get $M_0$ and show that for $Z=Re^{i\theta}$, $||f(Z)||\leq M_0/R^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Im studying complex variables by using  Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables. Apart from book I found a kind of exercises that asks to bound the function and find $M_0$ specific and $k$ possible according to $R_{min}$ given $z=Re^{i\theta}$ that it complies $||f(z)||\leq M_0/R^k$ depending $k \gt 0$ or $k \gt 1$

In the book there is only one similar exercise where we have the same conditions and the following function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^6+1}$$

With the condition and triangle inequality $$z_1=z^6 ; z_2 = 1$$
$$\lvert\lvert z\rvert^6-1\rvert\leqslant \lvert z^6+1\rvert\leqslant \lvert z^6\rvert+1$$

$$\lvert{f(z)}\rvert = \lvert{\frac{1}{z^6+1}}\rvert \leq \frac{1}{\lvert z^6 \rvert - \lvert 1 \rvert}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{\lvert R^6e^{6i\theta}\rvert - 1} = \frac{1}{R^6 - 1} $$

From which finally concludes the following

$$\frac{1}{R^6 - 1} \leq \frac{2}{R^6} = \frac{M_0}{R^k}$$

According to the book when R is large enough ($R \gt 2$, for example) we get those values ​​for $M_0$ and $k$

My question is, how do we get that last inequality and conclude that $M_0 = 2$ and $k = 6 \gt 1$?

**Update:** From The answers now i see that

$$\begin{align}\frac1{R^6-1}\leqslant\frac2{R^6}&\iff R^6\leqslant2R^6-2\\&\iff2\leqslant R^6\\&\iff R\geqslant\sqrt[6]2.\end{align}
$$

$$\frac2{R^6}=\frac{M_0}{R^k}$$

Thus any $R\geqslant\sqrt[6]2$ (largue enough) satisfies the inequality and for $ R \gt 2$ is valid.

However my main doubt is how can I interpret the condition $R_{min}$ (What does it mean) and why $R \gt 2$ was selected? For example, we can have the next inequality

$$\frac{1}{R^6 - 1} \leq \frac{2}{R^6} \leq \frac{3}{R^6} $$

And since it fulfills $||f(z)||\leq M_0/R^k$ then $M_0$ can also be $M_0=3$ or $M_0=2$. Under the condition $R_{min}$ only one of these $M_0$ can be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R>1$, then\begin{align}\frac1{R^6-1}\leqslant\frac2{R^6}&\iff R^6\leqslant2R^6-2\\&\iff2\leqslant R^6\\&\iff R\geqslant\sqrt[6]2.\end{align}So, $R=2$ will do. And we have$$\frac2{R^6}=\frac{M_0}{R^k}$$when $M_0=2$ and $k=6$.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos I still have a couple of doubts. How do we get from $R^6 \leq 2R^6 -2$ to $2 \leq 2R^6$? Also, $R_{min}$ we mean to the condition $R \gt 1$? If so, for example also $\frac{1}{R^6 - 1} \leq \frac{3}{R^6}$ would fulfill the condition but a different $M_0$ would be obtained?

Comment: We go from the first inequality to the second one by adding $2-R^6$ to both sides of the first one.

Comment: By adding $2-R^6$ to both sides $R^6 + (2-R^6) \leq 2R^6 - 2$ $+$ $(2-R^6)$ then $2 \leq R^6$ which is different.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Sorry about that.